# Update BOSH releases using knit

Tags: git, cloud-foundry, cf-bosh

I am using different BOSH releases, i.e., the [jumpbox-boshrelease](https://github.com/cloudfoundry-community/jumpbox-boshrelease) which I adapted to my requirements.
These releases have to be maintained.
For this, I want to download the updates from the community release and merge my own modifications into this repository.

I just tried to use the [knit tool](https://github.com/pivotal-cf-experimental/knit) to perform this. However, I do not understand how it is supposed to work.
For testing purposes I created only minor changes to the `README.md` (I added an additional line).

My `starting-versions.yml` looks like this:

```
---
starting_versions:
- version: 0
  ref: "master"
- version: 1
  ref: "master"
  patches:
  - "~/knit-test/test-knit.patch"
```

Does the patch file should be a git patch file?
I tried it with a git patch file and with a file which contains all changes.
I always receive the following error:

```
$ knit --repository-to-patch ~/knit-test/jumpbox-boshrelease --patch-repository ~/knit-test/jumpbox-boshrelease-mod --version 1.0.1
Already on 'master'
usage: git submodule [--quiet] add [-b <branch>] [-f|--force] [--name <name>] [--reference <repository>] [--] <repository> [<path>]
or: git submodule [--quiet] status [--cached] [--recursive] [--] [<path>...]
or: git submodule [--quiet] init [--] [<path>...]
or: git submodule [--quiet] deinit [-f|--force] [--] <path>...
or: git submodule [--quiet] update [--init] [--remote] [-N|--no-fetch] [-f|--force] [--rebase] [--reference <repository>] [--merge] [--recursive] [--] [<path>...]
or: git submodule [--quiet] summary [--cached|--files] [--summary-limit <n>] [commit] [--] [<path>...]
or: git submodule [--quiet] foreach [--recursive] <command>
or: git submodule [--quiet] sync [--recursive] [--] [<path>...]
```

```

I am not sure how knit is supposed to work, documentation is rare :smile:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This behaviour is a bug which can be tracked [on github](https://github.com/pivotal-cf-experimental/knit/issues/13#issuecomment-300526198).
The software assumes that every repository uses submodules that will also be patched. However, I do not use any submodules in this repository.

Answer (score 0):

We failed to reproduce this with the latest version of `knit` and `git` version `2.13.1`, What versions of `git` and `knit` are you using? Our starting versions looked like this:

```
---
starting_versions:
- version: 0
  ref: "master"
- version: 1
  ref: "master"
  patches:
  - 0001-Testing.patch
```

Please note that the path for the patch file in the starting-versions.yml is relative to the specified `patch-repository` command-line flag.